# Configuração MV Azure e SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, microsoft-azure, máquina-virtual

Preciso desenvolver um sistema para uma clinica médica e esse sistema será acessado por 2 Recepcionista e 2 Médicos. 
Inicialmente o Sistema não é complexo mas tende a crescer a medida que a Clinica contratará mais Médicos. 
Quero desenvolver em ASP.Net padrão MVC com Banco de Dados SQL Server. 
Diante desse cenário e pela experiência da comunidade gostaria de saber a opinião sobre a configuração da MV das Hospedagem Azure é suficiente levando em consideração que não haverá grande trafego de dados:

[Calculadora Azure:](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/calculator/#virtual-machines699b9b4d-5c33-4ccd-90f5-4085902c667c)
MV Azure - Camada Base;
Instância - A1, 1 Núcleo, 1,75 GB RAM, 40 GB de armazenamento
SQL Server - Licença SQL Web;

Entendo que a configuração acima é uma MV com SQL Server Instalado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que tem recurso mais que o suficiente, eu uso muito mais cliente em menos configuração. Mas eu não criei maquina virtual. Uso AppService e Serviço de banco de dados desligado de maquina virtual.